# How to get number of Executed, Scheduled and Cancelled bookings per month per year in sqlite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

[image: table-bookings]

This is the table and all its fields  and I am trying to get the number of executed, scheduled, and cancelled bookings per month per year in SQLite. Can anyone help, please? Thanks

Table fields: {id (INT), starttime(DATESTAMP), duration_hours(INT), user_id(INT), status(TEXT)}

id (booking id) is unique, starttime ranges between 2020 and 2022 (format: yyyy-mm-dd), user_id is not unique, status are either Executed, Scheduled or Cancelled.

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What have you tried so far, with a code example? / What do you expect? / What error do you get? For help, take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)".

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `strftime` function to extract the month and year from the date value, then use conditional count aggregated by the value of `strftime`.

```
Select strftime('%Y-%m', starttime) AS 'Month_Of_Year',
       COUNT(Case status When 'Executed' Then 1 Else Null End) AS 'Executed',
       COUNT(Case status When 'Scheduled' Then 1 Else Null End) AS 'Scheduled',
       COUNT(Case status When 'Cancelled' Then 1 Else Null End) AS 'Cancelled'
From Bookings
Group By strftime('%Y-%m', starttime)
Order By strftime('%Y-%m', starttime)
```

See a demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8a8590c2983e4481deeb21719bc16204).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ahmed. That's exactly what I wanted. I got the same answer but my approach was way too long.